# Domain Change with New Image Sizes

Tags: images

I am migrating domains and redesigning the site at the same time. My large image sizes are different than they were before. When I imported the old posts, I had it download all the images as well. My problem is that the images that were inserted with the old file size name. Is there a way to replace all of the images with the correct new image sizes? I just want it to use the default 'large' size, even though it is different than the original site.

In post html: 

Screen-shot-2010-11-30-at-8.03.27-PM-540x287.png

Actual image sizes: 

Screen-shot-2010-11-30-at-8.03.27-PM-525x279.png

Screen-shot-2010-11-30-at-8.03.27-PM-615x327.png

Answer (score 1):

Use plugin [Regenerate Thumbnails](http://www.viper007bond.com/wordpress-plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) to resize thumbnails.

Edit:

Try use filter "the_content" to convert in post content.

```
<?php

function foo ( $content )
{
    return preg_replace ('/540x287/', '525x279', $content);
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'foo' )
```

Filter "the_excerpt" if need convert excerpt too.

Comment: That's not the problem. I want to use my new 'large' size instead of the old sizing. It's not a question of having the right sized images, it's a question of having the html in all my posts pointing to the old size.

Comment: I add solution.